# Call to a member function getName() on null

Tags: php, laravel

I decided to dig into middleware, because I need to check on every request if the user is a pre-user (just a user that hasn't changed password yet), except for the change-password route. My code for the middleware is following:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class IsPreuser
{

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (\Auth::user()->is_preuser)
        {
            if (\Route::getCurrentRoute()->getName() == 'profile.change_password')
            {
                echo 'hello';
            }



            //return redirect()->route('profile.change_password');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

My route name is `profile.change_password`. With the above code I am getting the error `Call to a member function getName() on null` I don't understand. My goals are: to redirect to the `profile.change_password` route except when the user already is in this route.

My kernel.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\IsPreuser::class

    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            //Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,


        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    ];
}
```

Comment: Try `Route::currentRouteName()` instead

Comment: I tried, using `echo \Route::currentRouteName()` but nothing outputs.

Comment: How do you include this middleware to your code? Via `Http/Middleware/Kernel.php`? Include it it your post.

Comment: before the condition try dd(\Route::getCurrentRoute()); I am pretty sure you will get no results thats why u are getting null error on the getName()

Comment: It would only return anything on named routes. Basically you need `if (Route::currentRouteName() != 'profile.change_password') { return redirect...}`

Comment: I have edited the post to include `kernel.php`

Comment: Guys I fixed it, but another problem has occured. It also redirects when the user is logging out, which is not intended. How can I exclude the login?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, fixed it. As suggested in the comments, the problem could be the placement of my middleware. I moved it to `$middlewareGroups` in `web` and it works as expected, with the redirect.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class IsPreuser
{

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (\Auth::check())
        {
            if (\Auth::user()->is_preuser)
            {
                if (! $request->routeIs('profile.change_password') 
                    && ! $request->routeIs('profile.change_password_process') 
                    && ! $request->routeIs('logout'))
                {
                    return redirect()->route('profile.change_password');
                }
            }
        }


        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had same issue. had another issue:my middleware returns the no permission view and but executes the controller function as well!!

     return Response::make(view('noPermission'), 404);


Fixed following you. But my question is why middleware does this when add in protected $middleware[] array in kernel.php?